# Retaining same IP and hostname though AWS snapshot while launching new instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

I have created a snapshot of an instance and while launching the instance from this image i want to retain the same ip and hostname as that of the old instance. Is it possible in AWS?
After launching the instance the ip and hostname got changed.
Steps i followed. Through console i have selected the instance for which exact replica is required >image > create image selected instance and gave the same VPC subnet and all the same as that of the old ones

Answer (score 1):

This is what the elastic-ip functionality was created for. Yuu 'buy' an elastic ip, and then you can assign it to any instance in your account:

For more information: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: I have 2 queries  1. SO without elastic ip cant we retain same private ip address? 2. what about host is it  the same, cant we have same hostname?

Comment: I have 2 queries  1. Elastic Ip will create a new one but i want to have an ip which is already existing old one instance ip with associated instance shut down 2. what about host is it  the same, cant we have same hostname?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you already have a non-elastic ip, you can't retain it in this manner, and for the host name, it can be the same - you just need to register it with route53 or another dns provider and connect that elastic ip with the hostname - it just won't be the default aws host name, it would be one of your chooosing - i.e. mynewhost.com